# Why this Oracle job is only executed once?

Tags: oracle, plsql, jobs

I've an Oracle job defined as follows:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_job('clean_journal_partitions');
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name  => 'clean_journal_partitions',
    job_type  => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action => 'CLEAN_JOURNAL_PARTITION',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MON',
    auto_drop => FALSE);
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('clean_journal_partitions');
END;
```

That if I'm not wrong, it should be executed once a week every monday. The problem is that it is executed only once and I don't know why.

To be able to test it more easily, I've modified it to change the frequency from weekly to every 10 seconds, like this:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_job('clean_journal_partitions');
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name  => 'clean_journal_partitions',
    job_type  => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action => 'CLEAN_JOURNAL_PARTITION',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
    auto_drop => FALSE);
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('clean_journal_partitions');
END;
```

And I've the same problem. It is executed only once. Any hint why the job is not executed every 10 seconds?

Comment: Check the view user_scheduler_jobs and see what is the status of your job. Check the views user_scheduler_job_run_details and user_scheduler_job_log for any errors in your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in Oracle 11g:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
    run_time DATE
); 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLEAN_JOURNAL_PARTITION AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(SYSDATE);
    COMMIT;
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name  => 'clean_journal_partitions',
    job_type  => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action => 'CLEAN_JOURNAL_PARTITION',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
    auto_drop => FALSE);
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('clean_journal_partitions');
END;
```

I get one entry in the `TEST` table every 10 seconds. Your problem must be in your `CLEAN_JOURNAL_PARTITION` procedure, maybe it crashes?